# @spread no tiene el comportamiento esperado en lighthouse (Graphql en Laravel 8.x)

Tags: laravel, graphql, lighthouse

Estoy creando un `mutation` personalizado, el cual creará desde un `array` de `interactionInput` sus respectivos registros.

El problema es que en el `mutation` personalizado los datos me llegan dentro de una clave `input`, siendo que `@spread` deberia encargarse de pasar directamente los datos y eliminar dicha clave (*Por lo que tengo entendido, puedo estar equivocado*).

Definición:

```
input interactionInput{
    phrase_id: ID!,
    action: InteractionType!
}

type interaction {
    user_id: ID!,
    phrase_id: ID!,
    action: InteractionType!
}
```

Mutation:

```
createOrUpdateInteractions(input: [interactionInput!] @spread) : [interaction]! @guard(with: ["api"])
```

Lo que obtengo como `$args` para mi mutation:

```
array:1 [
  "input" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "phrase_id" => "1"
      "action" => "like"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "phrase_id" => "2"
      "action" => "like"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Lo que espero obtener:

```
array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "phrase_id" => "1"
      "action" => "like"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "phrase_id" => "2"
      "action" => "like"
    ]
  ]
```

La forma en que se resuelve mi `mutation` es mediante la conversión de nombres comenzando por mayúscula (`CreateOrUpdateInteractions`) (*No sé si esto tiene algo que ver realmente, soy nuevo con graphql*).

Comment: La notación en la documentación es sin `[ ]` (input: interactionInput! @spread)

Comment: @L.Flor Pero yo quiero recibir un ````array```` de ````interactionInput````, por lo cual necesito que esté dentro de ````[]````, del contrario no me funciona, ya que espera directamente el ````input````. 
También intenté agregar el ````@spread```` dentro del array pero obtengo un error de sintaxis (Lo que tiene algo de sentido)

¿Será que ````@spread```` no funciona con ````array````?